# Microsoft Graph api throwing MaxRequestDurationExceeded error?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to read the range of the excel file from the sharepoint so  I have using microsoft graph. But randomly it is throwing the following issue.

`{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"MaxRequestDurationExceeded\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Service Unavailable.\",\r\n    \"innerError\": {\r\n      \"request-id\": \"ddd-9a30-eee-927a-fff\",\r\n      \"date\": \"2018-04-24T10:37:29\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"MaxRequestDurationExceeded","message":"Service Unavailable.","innerError":{"request-id":"5ef4e30d-9a30-48a0-927a-8a540e96f495","date":"2018-04-24T10:37:29"}}},"status":504,"statusText":"Gateway Timeout"} collection https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx.sharepoint.com,aaa,bbb/drives/ccc/items/dddN/workbook/worksheets('Toc-Master')/usedRange?$select=values`

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Maybe search or submit as issue https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=request